# How to apply libxml2 patches to Freebsd?

Tags: freebsd

How can i apply a libxml2 patch for the issue "UnassignXMLSoft libxml2 String Substitutions Remote Denial of Service Vulnerability" to the older version of libxml2 like 2.7.6 in FreeBsd machine?

Comment: What is your FreeBSD version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of `libxml2` in [FreeBSD ports](https://www.freebsd.org/ports/) is 2.9.1.

[Update](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html) your ports tree, and then update your installed ports using e.g. [portmaster](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portmaster&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports).

If you want to apply a patch by hand, it *generally* goes something like this;

- Unpack the libxml2-2.7.6 source code.
- `cd` into the source code directory
- `patch < /path/to/patch-file`
- Compile as usual.

Comment: That's true, but I need libxml2-2.7.6 version, so I need to apply the patch, so I need the process, how to apply the patch

Comment: It looks good, but can u please explain in little detail about the step "patch < /path/to/patch-file"

Comment: and also pls help me on how to unpack the libxml2 source code.

Comment: @nandukishore Are you building from the FreeBSD ports system?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's true